# How to append more columns to a structural datafame in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes (A and B), A is a structural schema whereas B is a common schema as below and will append B columns into A for C

A:

```
root
|-- package: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- globalPackageId: long (nullable = true)
|    |-- naPackageId: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- packageName: string (nullable = true)
|-- supplies: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- supplyMask: integer (nullable = true)
|    |-- supplyIds: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
|-- timestampDetails: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- packageTimestamp: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- onboardTimestamp: string (nullable = true)
```

B:

```
root
 |-- globalPackageId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- order_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- order_address: string (nullable = true)
 |-- order_number: integer (nullable = true)
```

C:

```
root
|-- package: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- globalPackageId: long (nullable = true)
|    |-- naPackageId: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- packageName: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- order_id: long (nullable = true)
|    |-- order_address: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- order_number: integer (nullable = true)
|-- supplies: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- supplyMask: integer (nullable = true)
|    |-- supplyIds: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
|-- timestampDetails: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- packageTimestamp: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- onboardTimestamp: string (nullable = true)
```

I am struggling to use .withColumn(struct("xxx"), "xxx")
But looks still not expected
Do you have any experience on this

Thanks,

Comment: I am sorry that I forgot to add the important information in it. I have revised my example above. The joining condition column is globalPackageId. Using Part A left join Part B to have a new dataset Part C. Thanks